# How iterate through a list of class attributes and change their values?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to create a function, that if the user did not enter any value in input field then it sets the text value to 0 or to any other number.

```
    value_text = [self.trig_side_a_value.text, self.trig_side_b_value.text, self.trig_side_c_value.text, self.trig_angle_A_value.text, self.trig_angle_B_value.text, self.trig_angle_C_value.text]
    for i in value_text:
        if i == "":
            i = "0"
        else:
            pass
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Lists hold *objects*.

Comment: I think what you need is an [__init__](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__init__-in-python/) function to set object attributes to their default values.

Comment: Probably you need 'default arguments': https://stackabuse.com/default-arguments-in-python-functions/

Comment: why don't you set a default value using hint_text

Answer (score 0):

OK, so there is quite a bit wrong here. I will try to answer this with as much explanation as possible.

One thing that is wrong:

```
value_text = [self.trig_side_a_value.text, self.trig_side_b_value.text, self.trig_side_c_value.text, self.trig_angle_A_value.text, self.trig_angle_B_value.text, self.trig_angle_C_value.text]
    for i in value_text:
        if i == "":
            i = "0"
```

This creates a list `value_text` and populates it with copies of the text attributes. Changing what is in the list does not affect the elements of self..text.

What needs to happen is that you need to iterate through the attributes of the class, setting each attributes' `text` member:

Here is a solution:

```
class TextContainer():
    """ This is a class with just one attribute 'text' """
    def __init__(self, text=""):
        self.text = text


class TestClass():
    """ This class contains a set of TextContainer objects as its attributes. """
    def __init__(self):
        self.trig_side_a_value = TextContainer("a")
        self.trig_side_b_value = TextContainer("b")
        self.trig_side_c_value = TextContainer()
        self.trig_angle_A_value = TextContainer("A")
        self.trig_angle_B_value = TextContainer("B")
        self.trig_angle_C_value = TextContainer()

    def test_me(self):
        """ Test the setting of each attribute """
        for attr, container in self.__dict__.items():
            if not container.text:
                container.text = "0"

    def __str__(self):
        """ Returns a string representation of the class """
        return "TestClass: ({}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {})".format(
            self.trig_side_a_value.text,
            self.trig_side_b_value.text,
            self.trig_side_c_value.text,
            self.trig_angle_A_value.text,
            self.trig_angle_B_value.text,
            self.trig_angle_C_value.text)


def main():
    test = TestClass()
    test.test_me()
    print(test)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Hope that helps. Others, please correct my usage of the `__dict__` - I'm some shaky ground here.